# Get polygon coordinates from geojson in yii framework

Tags: php, postgresql, yii, geojson

I use Yii framework with GeoExt to develop map based web application.In this app i have a feature that user can draw polygon and when click on it i send polygon information with ajax to controller action to save this polygon on database.For saving polygon on database i need coordinates of polygon.For get polygon coordinates i use below code in my controller action.But i don't know i can get polygon coordinates or no for understand about it i send coordinates to $.ajax success function in my action code but i get error in my browser console!
**Action Code:**

```
public function actionTest()
{
   if(isset($_POST['polygon']) && isset($_POST['name'])){
            $str = $_POST['polygon'];
            $polygon = CJSON::decode($str);
            $coordinates = $polygon->polygon->geometry->coordinates[0];
   }
   echo CJSON::encode(array('polygon'=> $coordinates));
}
```

**$.ajax code:**

```
function save(feature) {
        var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
        var str = geojson_format.write(feature);
        str = str.replace(/,/g, ', ');
        Ext.MessageBox.prompt('Name', 'Please enter district name:', function(btn, text){
                if (btn == 'ok' && text.length > 0){
                    <?php 
                        echo CHtml::ajax(array(
                            'url'=>array('site/test'),
                            'data'=>array('polygon'=>'js:str',
                                'name'=>'js:text'),
                            'type'=>'POST',

                            'success'=>"function(data){
                                    console.log(data);
                                }"
                        ));
                    ?>
                    $("#output").val(str);
                }
                else if(btn == 'ok' && text.length == 0)
                    Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error', 'Please Enter Name For Polygon To Save');
            });
}
```

Error in browser console:

```
POST http://localhost/FleetManagement/index.php/site/test 500 (PHP Error) jquery.js:8102 jQuery.ajaxTransport.send jquery.js:8102 jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7580 modify.mode/FleetManagement/:254(anonymous function)
```

But when i use below code for action i can get String in console:

```
public function actionTest()
{
   if(isset($_POST['polygon']) && isset($_POST['name'])){
            $str = $_POST['polygon'];
            $polygon = CJSON::decode($str);
   }
   echo CJSON::encode(array('polygon'=> $polygon ));
}
```

after using above code i can get below string in browser console:

```
{"polygon":{"type":"Feature","properties":[],"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-7302732.4720101,6527844.6333235],[-3193477.8319711,6606116.1502766],[-5111129.9973226,5001550.0527375],[-6637424.5779086,4884142.7773079],[-7772361.5737289,5158093.0866438],[-7302732.4720101,6527844.6333235]]]},"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}}}}
```

why i can't get coordinates and how can i do this?
I see below code for output of var_dump in chrome console!

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b>
'type' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Feature'</font> <i>(length=7)</i>
'properties' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
<b>array</b>
<i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
'geometry' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
<b>array</b>
'type' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Polygon'</font> <i>(length=7)</i>
'coordinates' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
<b>array</b>
0 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
<b>array</b>
 ...
'crs' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
<b>array</b>
'type' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'name'</font> <i>(length=4)</i>
'properties' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
<b>array</b>
```

i don't know why coordinates doesn't appear in console an show ... stead of themes!

Comment: I want to test that can i get coordinates of polygon in browser console and after testing it save polygon in database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're trying to pass the polygon coordinates back out; it sounds as if you should be saving it into the database in your actionTest, and there's no need to send it back to the client?

In any case, I think your code should be throwing a PHP error at this line:

```
$coordinates = $polygon->polygon->geometry->coordinates[0];
```

Are you sure $polygon is an object?  I would think that it's an array, so you would need to use array reference, e.g.:

```
$coordinates = $polygon['polygon']['geometry']['coordinates'][0];
```

In any case, do some var_dump()'s in your actionTest to make sure the values are what you expect them to be before passing it back to your JS.

Comment: I changed my code to `$coordinates = $polygon['polygon']['geometry']['coordinates'][0];`But i get same error for it!.var_dump doesn't work because i send data via ajax to server how can i use var_dump in ajax at action?Action doesn't render any view to use var_dump!.I use this site to check my $polygon structure to get coordinates.http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ You can see my string structure in this site!.I'm so confused about this problem

Comment: how can i use var_dump in action because when i use in my action code i only see html format of $polygon and i can't see coordinates into it!

Comment: var_dump() output in your action should be viewable in the debug console of Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools

Comment: I edit my question and add var_dump output in console but i don't know why code doesn't work and show php error in console!.When i send $polygon stead of $coordinates i see string in my question But with coordinates i get error!.Can you help me?

Comment: Your questions keep demonstrating a fundamental lack of understanding of PHP and Javascript, namely that one is server-side and the other is client-side, and you need to pass data between them, usually using JSON.  I'm sorry, but I'm going to have to stop answering your questions until you understand than, and then learn some basic debugging steps (e.g. how to use debug consoles, check variable values, etc).

Comment: I know that php is server side and js is client side and as you can see in my code i pass polygon geojson variable very well from js to php and get it in the php code and passed it to js.I see var_dump output in my console but because it doesn't showed coordinates in the console i didn't write it in my question.As you can see in var_dump output it is array but i don't know why i can't get coordinates from it!

Comment: stead of var_dump i use print_r in my action function and i see $polygon structure in the console log and edit my code to `$coordinates = $polygon['geometry']['coordinates'][0];`And this code works well :D

Comment: glad you got it to work . . . both print_r and var_dump should provide similar output

Comment: Thanks.I don't know why var_dump make html output!.I attach var_dump output in my question!.